# Slight Delay while trying to print out synced lyrics in music bot

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord

So I'm trying to build a private custom bot in pycord where it shows real time lyrics are they're being sung in the song. To do this I uploaded the song file and it's .lrc file both.
The first lyrics gets printed as it should but from the next iterations, the asyncio.sleep part is getting delayed and I can't understand why.

Attaching the code with the snippet from the .lrc file and the debug output.

**Code:**

```
import os
import asyncio
import pylrc

song_lrc_mapping = {
    "This Town.mp3": "This Town.lrc"
}
 
def load_lyrics_lrc(song_url):
  if song_url in song_lrc_mapping:
    lrc_filename = song_lrc_mapping[song_url]

    try:
      with open(lrc_filename, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as lrc_file:
        lrc_data = lrc_file.read()
        lrc = pylrc.parse(lrc_data)
        return lrc
    except FileNotFoundError:
      return []
  else:
    return []


@client.slash_command()
async def play(ctx):
  voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
  voice_client = ctx.guild.voice_client

  if voice_client is None:
    voice_client = await voice_channel.connect()

  
  for song_url in song_lrc_mapping: 
    try:
      audio_source = discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(song_url)
      voice_client.stop()  
      voice_client.play(audio_source) 

      await ctx.send(f"Playing song: {song_url}") 


      lyrics = load_lyrics_lrc(song_url) 
      a = True
      first_time = lyrics[0].time

      for lyric_line in lyrics: 
        
        
        seconds = (lyric_line.time - first_time)
        seconds = round(seconds, 2)
        line = lyric_line.text
        
        
        if a is True:
          a = False
          await asyncio.sleep(first_time)
          embed = discord.Embed(title="Song Lyrics", description=line, color=discord.Color.blue()) 
          b = await ctx.send(embed=embed) 
        else:
          print(lyric_line.time)
          print(first_time)
          print(seconds)  
          await asyncio.sleep(seconds) 
          embed = discord.Embed(title="Song Lyrics", description=line, color=discord.Color.blue()) 
          await b.edit(embed=embed) 
        
        first_time = lyric_line.time

        

    except Exception as e:
      print(e) 
      await ctx.send(f"An error occurred while playing {song_url}: {e}") 
      
client.run(os.environ['token'])
```

**Snippet from .lrc file:**

```
[re:www.megalobiz.com/lrc/maker]
[ve:v1.2.3]
[00:03.50]Waking up to kiss you and nobody's there
[00:08.26]The smell of your perfume still stuck in the air
[00:12.50]It's hard
[00:16.56]Yesterday I thought I saw your shadow running 'round
[00:21.31]It's funny how things never change in this old town
[00:25.56]So far
[00:29.06]From the stars
```

**Song used:** [This Town.mp3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ic1l36GrNOU)

**Debug Output:**

```
8.26
3.5
4.76
12.5
8.26
4.24
16.56
12.5
4.06
21.31
16.56
4.75
25.56
21.31
4.25
29.06
25.56
3.5
34.56
29.06
5.5
```

The delay starts from 12.5

Comment: Maybe you are running into a ratelimit or something?

Comment: I don't think I'll get rate limited when the time between them is in seconds but I'll add a rate limit check and get back to you about it

Comment: Hey, i checked if the bot is getting rate limited by using `client.is_ws_ratelimited()` inside the for loop to see if its getting rate limited after sleeping. But it returns False and the delay still exists so im guessing the issue is something else.